# Return value from angularjs factory

Tags: angularjs, websocket

I try to set up this example https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket#usage
Here is my code

```
App.factory('MyData', function($websocket, $q) {
var dataStream = $websocket('wss://url');
var collection = [];

dataStream.onMessage(function(message) {
    var result = JSON.parse(message.data);
    console.log(result);
    collection = result;
});

var methods = {
    collection: collection,
    get: function() {
        dataStream.send(JSON.stringify({
            api: "volume",
            date: "2017-02-01",
            interval: 600
        }));
    }
};

return methods; });
```

In my controller I wrote:

```
$interval(function () {
    console.log(MyData.collection);
}, 1000);
```

The problem is that I don't receive any values, however on message arrive I see console log, so websocket itself is obviously alive. If I change `collection.push(result)` (like in example) I receive constantly growing array. I need only the last value, however. Why `collection = result` is wrong ?

Comment: `collection.push(result)` shouldn't work as collection is defined as an `Object` push is an `Array` function

Comment: It defined as array. Sorry, I copy-pasted my already broken code. Fixed initial message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var collection = [];` instantiates a new array and its reference is stored in the variable `collection`. Then, this reference is assigned to `methods.collection` and, hence, `MyData.collection`. However, with `JSON.parse` a new array is instantiated. `collection = result;` overwrites the original reference with the reference of the new array. But `MyData.collection` still holds the reference to original array.

So, there are two ways to encounter the problem:

1. Don't overwrite the reference to the original array. `push` is good, but before, you need to clear the array in order to only show the last value.

```js
collection.splice(0, collection.length);
collection.push(result);
```

However, that would be an array in an array. You probably need to push the values individually (`Array.concat` will create a new array, too):

```
collection.splice(0, collection.length);
result.forEach(function(value) {
  collection.push(value);
});
```

2. Assign the reference of the new array directly to `methods.collection`. In this case, no extra variable `collection` is needed.

```js
App.factory('MyData', function($websocket, $q) {
  var dataStream = $websocket('wss://url');

  var methods = {
    collection: [],
    get: function() {
        dataStream.send(JSON.stringify({
            api: "volume",
            date: "2017-02-01",
            interval: 600
        }));
    }
  };

  dataStream.onMessage(function(message) {
    var result = JSON.parse(message.data);
    console.log(result);
    methods.collection = result;
  });

  return methods;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The second way looks lighter.